# Conversion requires reinterpret_cast error building with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I have the following error when compiling my source code via CMake on Windows using MSVC 120 ,Visual Studio 2013.When I build directly from VisualStudio I have no errors.It happens only if I build via command line after generating CMake build files.

> error C2664: 'void gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator *,GLenum,void
>   (__stdcall *)(void))' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'GLvoid
>   (__cdecl * (void)' to 'void (__stdcall *)(void)'
>            This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast

The actual code is this function:

```
 static void edgeFlagCallback(GLboolean)
 {
        //some code here
 }

 void MyClass:Foo()
 {
    gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_EDGE_FLAG   ,reinterpret_cast<GLvoid ( *)()>(edgeFlagCallback));
 }
```

It also compiles ok on Linux with GCC.Maybe I have to set some additional compiler argument,but so far I didn't find what.Also I don't understand the error because I do use cast in this case.
These are the flags I am adding for the MSVC project in CMake:

```
add_definitions(-DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -D_LIB -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
```

Comment: Which command prompt are you using? x86 or x64?

Comment: I tried to add Win64 but it looks like it compiles with x86 by default.In VisualStudio I target x64 .Maybe I have to upgrade the CMake.I have currently version 3.0

Comment: Visual Studio should come with several different command prompts one for x86 and one for x64. The issue you are having only occurs on x86.

Comment: I see,but I can't figure out how to invoke it through CMake command prompt command.Tried : cmake -G"Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" and it looks like it still uses x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gluTessCallback function expects a function of type *GLvoid (__stdcall *) (void)* as third parameter. So the __stdcall (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) is part of the function signature.

__stdcall and __cdecl are ignored on x64 builds. That is why it works in VS and Linux but not with the command prompt (x86).

Visual Studio 2013 comes with three different cmds: 
[image: VS command prompts]

To build 64bit binaries with cmake the *x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt* has to be used.

Comment: Yeah,thanks for that info,I figured that out also but couldn't understand how to launch x64 cmd tool from CMake.Now it looks like I should just run Cmake build via this cmd.I look for a way to automate it so tht CMake can be invoked from any cmd and build it with x64 toolchain.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx#Anchor_1